# Abort a running function on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, abort

I have a web page which has a feature where when we click on pdf, it fetches the values of printers on the go. It takes some time, so on repeated clicks, the webpage crashes.

Is there any way where we can abort the current running of the function or can somehow disable the button click after once clicked?

UI Code:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
 <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgExportPDF" />
    </Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
        <table id="topHeading" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="PageHeader">
            <tr align="center" style="height: 25px" class="PageHeader2">
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="width: 30%" visible="false">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExportPDF" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/pdf-Export.jpg"

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And my backend code:

```
protected void imgExportPDF_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    saveDetails();

    int counterAdd = 0;

    DataSet dsDevNotReady = CDBIntract.GetDevNotReady(EnterpriseV, CDInfonew.Count);
    if (dsDevNotReady != null)
    {
        if (dsDevNotReady.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dsDevNotReady.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append((deviceCounter + 1) + ". IP Address : " + dsDevNotReady.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IPAddress"].ToString() + "  And Model Name : " + dsDevNotReady.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Model"].ToString() + "  On Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + dsDevNotReady.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Info"].ToString());
                sb.Append("\r\n");
                deviceCounter++;
            }
            counterAdd++;
        }
    }

    int countData = 0;
    DataSet dsdev= CDBIntract.Blah(EnterpriseV, CDInfonew.Count);

    if (dsDev != null)
    {

        if (dsDev.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            countData = dsDev.Tables[0].Rows.Count + Convert.ToInt32(dsDev.Tables[1].Rows[0]["AditionalRows1"].ToString()) + Convert.ToInt32(dsDev.Tables[2].Rows[0]["AditionalRows2"].ToString());
            PdfDocument myPdfDocument = new PdfDocument(PdfDocumentFormat.A4);
            PdfTable myPdfTable = myPdfDocument.NewTable(new Font("Verdana", 8), countData + counterAdd, 2, 4);
            myPdfTable.ImportDataTable(returnTable(dsDev, deviceCounter, sb.ToString()));

            //Set PDF Table Style
            myPdfTable.HeadersRow.SetFont(new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold));
            myPdfTable.HeadersRow.SetColors(System.Drawing.Color.Gray, System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
            myPdfTable.SetColors(Color.Black, Color.White, Color.White);
            myPdfTable.SetBorders(Color.Gray, 1, BorderType.CompleteGrid);

            myPdfTable.SetColumnsWidth(new int[] { 30, 30 });
            int[] arrayDevice = listDevice.ToArray();
            for (int m = 0; m < arrayDevice.Length; m++)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (PdfCell pc in myPdfTable.CellRange(arrayDevice[m], 0, arrayDevice[m], 0).Cells)
                    {
                        pc.ColSpan = 2;
                        pc.SetCellPadding(4);
                        pc.SetColors(Color.Red, Color.LightGray);
                        pc.SetFont(new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
            int[] array = list.ToArray();
            for (int m = 0; m < array.Length; m++)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (PdfCell pc in myPdfTable.CellRange(array[m], 0, array[m], 0).Cells)//(0//,0//,0//Number of rows,0//column)
                    {
                        pc.ColSpan = 2;
                        pc.SetCellPadding(4);
                        pc.SetColors(Color.Blue, Color.LightGray);
                        pc.SetFont(new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
            int[] array1 = list2.ToArray();
            for (int n = 0; n < array1.Length; n++)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (PdfCell pc in myPdfTable.CellRange(array1[n], 0, array1[n], 0).Cells)//(0//,0//,0//Number of rows,0//column)
                    {
                        pc.ColSpan = 2;
                        pc.SetCellPadding(4);
                        pc.SetColors(Color.Blue, Color.LightGray);
                        pc.SetFont(new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
            int[] array2 = list3.ToArray();
            for (int k = 0; k < array2.Length; k++)
            {
                try
                {

                    foreach (PdfCell pc in myPdfTable.CellRange(array2[k], 0, array2[k], 0).Cells)//(0//,0//,0//Number of rows,0//column)
                    {
                        pc.ColSpan = 2;
                        pc.SetCellPadding(4);
                        //pc.SetColors(Color.Blue, Color.LightGray);
                        if (k == 0)
                            pc.SetFont(new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            myPdfTable.SetRowHeight(100);
            // Now we set some alignment... for the whole table and then, for a column.
            myPdfTable.SetContentAlignment(ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft);

            string logo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "/images/Printeaze_Logo02.jpg";
            PdfImage LogoImage = myPdfDocument.NewImage(logo);

            string companylogo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "/images/CompanyLogo.jpg";
            PdfImage CompanyLogo = myPdfDocument.NewImage(companylogo);

            int i = 0;
            PdfTablePage newPdfTablePage;

            // Here we start the loop to generate the table...
            while (!myPdfTable.AllTablePagesCreated)
            {
                // we create a new page to put the generation of the new TablePage:
                i++;

                PdfPage newPdfPage = myPdfDocument.NewPage();

                if (i == 1)
                {

                    newPdfTablePage =
                        myPdfTable.CreateTablePage(new PdfArea(myPdfDocument, 18, 120, 560, 680));
                    // newPdfTablePage =
                    //     myPdfTable.CreateTablePage(new PdfArea(myPdfDocument, 18, 120, 560, 450));

                    newPdfPage.Add(LogoImage, 460, 30, 120);
                    newPdfPage.Add(CompanyLogo, 20, 20, 120);
                    // we also put a Label 
                    PdfTextArea pta = new PdfTextArea(new Font("Verdana", 16, FontStyle.Bold), Color.Black
                        , new PdfArea(myPdfDocument, 20, 70, 350, 20), ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, "Blah");

                    newPdfPage.Add(newPdfTablePage);
                    newPdfPage.Add(pta);
                    //PointF pointstart = new PointF(20, 140);
                    //PointF pointend = new PointF(578, 140);
                }
                else
                {
                    newPdfTablePage = myPdfTable.CreateTablePage(new PdfArea(myPdfDocument, 18, 15, 560, 800));
                    // newPdfTablePage = myPdfTable.CreateTablePage(new PdfArea(myPdfDocument, 18, 15, 600, 650));
                    newPdfPage.Add(newPdfTablePage);
                }

                newPdfPage.SaveToDocument();
            }
            // Finally we save the docuement...
            //myPdfDocument.SaveToFile("PDF.pdf");
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            myPdfDocument.SaveToStream(stream);
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= Blah.pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to disable the button when it's clicked.

If that's not enough, you need to keep track of (store in a static list or something) the user sessions in your code-behind and check whether a specific session has started but not finished the PDF call and simply exit the duplicate calls if the first one isn't completed.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

This will require various safe-guards which increases complexity to prevent a user getting locked-out of the PDF generation completely in case of an error.